# Changing the src of some javascript files dynamically

Tags: html

I am working on a cool styleswitcher, but the issue which I can't pass through is changing not just the stylesheet but too js files. The whole style for my template is included in one css file and more js files (before you ask me why not included everything in the css file, because in that way some not worked as fine as I wanted).

I want that on click of a div to change the stylesheet and some javascript's src. I can do the changing part of the stylesheets, but have no idea how to do the same thing with the js files with html.

For exemple:
On click of the ".color-orange" div change these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" title="default"/>
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
<script src="js/exemple.js"></script>
```

To these:

```
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="css/style-orange.css" type="text/css" title="orange">
<script src="js/global-orange.js"></script>
<script src="js/exemple-orange.js"></script>
```

The code, I am using:

```
<li><a href="/" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('default'); return false;"><div class="color-default"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="/" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('orange'); return false;"><div class="color-orange"></div></a></li>
```

Thanks in advance! I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Why do you need to change your javascript to change a color.

Comment: Because some of the colors are included in js files, and no, I can't include them in the css files :(.

Comment: changing scripts and styles on the fly its very expensive. If you are still thinking on doing it i would recommend you to pre-load all the assets and just switch (activate/deactivate) to prevent from downloading every time they are needed.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to rewrite my js files to not include the colors there, so will not need to change the js files. Thank for the suggestion :). I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its basic use of jQuery, at first I've named each a tag in id (default and orange), then I created jQuery functions, when one of the links is clicked the link href will change by using the method .attr().

```
<li><a href="#" id="default"><div class="color-default"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="orange"><div class="color-orange"></div></a></li>

$('#default').click(function({
 $( "link" ).attr({
   href: "/default.css",
 });
});

$('#orange').click(function({
 $( "link" ).attr({
   href: "/orange.css",
 });
});
```

Comment: And there can I include the src of js files too? I mean like this: ({ src: "/orange.css", src: "/script1.js", src: "/script2.js", });

Comment: You can use the same code only with src and different files.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to rewrite my js files to not include the colors there, so will not need to change the js files. If I can't I will use your version. Thanks! :)

Comment: @PrinceBuzas Alright, you might consider using string if I understood your target correctly.